# Cannot install SQL Server 2008 R2 service pack 1

Tags: sql-server-2008

upgraded SQL 2008 t0 2008 R2 the other day.
Rebooted the server had the software team check the databases.
Everything worked fine

I tried installing 2008 r2 service pack 1 and the installation failed with a reference to look at the summary.txt file.
I looked at the file but couldn't tell why it failed.

I would like to know what I must do in order to get service pack 1 installed?
I would like to do it without removing SQL and re-installing.
I also have 2008 express installed that I will be upgrading to 2008 r2.

Comment: The output of that summary file would probably be helpful for us.

Answer (score 0):

Does the upgrade pass all the prerequisites?  Again as Tim said above the summary file will help troubleshooting this further.